# target.is() for DropDownList - MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this JQuery function that will not execute if the item in question is a `button` or `input`, and now I want to add `DropDownList` to this condition.

How do I do this?

**Query's if-statement** *I tried using* `selector` *as my best guess*

```
if (!$(e.target).is('button') && !$(e.target).is('input') && !$(e.target).is('selector'))
```

**my View**

```
<td class="col-lg-3">
    <span class="item-display">
           <span style="font-size: 17px">
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.Location1)
           </span>
     </span>
     <span class="item-field">
         @Html.DropDownList("locationID", item.Location.Location1)
     </span>
</td>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is it not just adding `&& !$(e.target).is('select'))` to your `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just view the HTML and it will give it away. The `@Html.DropDownList()` creates a `<select>` object.

The following should work:

```
!$(e.target).is('select')
```

By the way, your jquery can be dramatically simplified (untested):

```
if (!$(e.target).is('button, input, select'))
```

Comment: Ah sorry :( I am brand new to all of this and forgot about checking the Intellisense. I was searching for a possible answer via MSDN's definition of DropDownList and they don't even mention `select`. Thank you!

Comment: It happens. Welcome to MVC, it's a very pleasant coding language overall!

Comment: Yea I am absolutely loving it! (along with Bootstrap). Thank you again! *will award answer when timer expires*

Answer (score 0):

The HTML element for a drop down is `select` so just change your statement to this:

```
if (!$(e.target).is('button') && !$(e.target).is('input') && !$(e.target).is('select'))
```